# Would a VPN over TOR connection be a better option if I trust my VPN provider?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, proxy, tor

I understand that running TOR through a VPN provides extra encryption because it routes your data through the VPN and then encrypts until it finally goes in the TOR entry nodes and leaves in the exit nodes. theoretically if i were to use NORDVPN over TOR would it be a more secure option because my data can't be traced back to the source of my VPN? NordVPN claims that they save no logs but would they cooperate with federal officials if they were asked to?

Comment: They are based in Panama - I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

In this flow:

you@isp -> TOR -> you@NORDVPN -> site

NORDVPN will always know it is you reaching the site. To them is the same if you are using Tor or are travelling abroad.

So, if you trust your VPN provider, going through Tor won't help much (somethings will be different, for example your ISP will not longer know you are using NORDVPN, but will know you are using TOR).

And if somebody gets the information the VPN provider, your billing information will say a lot more than your origin IP.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that running TOR through a VPN provides extra encryption because it routes your data through the VPN and then encrypts until it finally goes in the TOR entry nodes and leaves in the exit nodes.

Your data between your VPN and the client is already encrypted.  I am not sure I agree there is any benefit to connecting to a VPN then connecting to TOR.  NordVPN knows who you are, they can literally identify, who is using their service.  They can also identify which clients were connected to TOR nodes during a specific time frame.  If you are using the configuration you describe to protect your identity, that isn't actually happening, since NordVPN has your payment information.

> if i were to use NORDVPN over TOR would it be a more secure option because my data can't be traced back to the source of my VPN?

I personally don't believe connecting to a VPN then connecting to the TOR network would be more secure then just connecting to the TOR network.  Your connect to your VPN is already encrypted.  **I don't personally see a huge different between your ISP being able to identify you and your VPN being able to identify you.**

> NordVPN claims that they save no logs but would they cooperate with federal officials if they were asked to?

If NordVPN does not save logs, then how would they be able to cooperate with federal officials, since there are no logs there is nothing to be sent to those federal officials.

There was a case a few years ago of a college student who was not prepared for an exam.  They decided they would connect to the TOR network and send a bomb threat to the college.  The college was able to identify the student who sent the bomb threat, since this student was the only student connected to the TOR network, when the email was sent.  **The only reason I mention this story, is to highlight the fact, the TOR network does not guarantee anonymity.**

Background: [FBI agents tracked Harvard bomb threats despite Tor](https://www.theverge.com/2013/12/18/5224130/fbi-agents-tracked-harvard-bomb-threats-across-tor)

**If your ISP and VPN both know who you are, then it is difficult to be anonymous, while being connected to the TOR network.**

Comment: @AgentOrange - If you are paying for the proxy you have just introduced yet another party who can identify you.  It all depends what your goal is.  If you are after.  If you are after anonymity paying for services won't achieve that goal.  You would have to pay in something like in BitCoin (which does not provide 100% anonymity either) and run your own services (on your own hardware you own) configured in such a way where you actually know for a fact no logs are kept.  However, I have answered the question as it was asked, I don't answer questions submitted as a comment.

Comment: @AgentOrange - I am not going to answer any questions asked within a comment.  We have a community dedicated to Bitcoin, if you want to know about Bitcoin, you should ask Bitcoin related questions there..  Your question as it's currently written as been answered.